# Slideshow with specific Text on each Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, slideshow

So I made this little Slideshow with HTML/CSS/JS and I want to add Text to each of the 6 Images, but I cant figure out how to do so, since I can only change the Text of my 1st Image. Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

```js
var imagecount = 1;
var total = 6;

function slide(x) {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagecount = imagecount + x;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
}

window.setInterval(function slideA(x) {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagecount = imagecount + 1;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
}, 3000);
```

```css
#container {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
}
#left_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#right_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 37%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text1">Text</div>
  <img src="images/img1.jpg" id="img" />
  <div id="left_holder">
    <img onClick="slide(-1)" class="left" src="images/arrow_left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="right_holder">
    <img onClick="slide(1)" class="right" src="images/arrow_right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to append a new text to every image that gets called. 
In order to do this I suggest you add this function and call it every time a new image is called(and the end of `slide()`):

```
function ChangeText(imgNum){
      var allImagesAndText = {1: "This is image 1", 2: "This is image 2"};
      document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = allImagesAndText[imgNum];
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with"and the end of slide()"? So i added your function to my java script but i doesnt seem to work

Comment: function slide(x) {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagecount = imagecount + x;
  if (imagecount > total) {
    imagecount = 1;
  }
  if (imagecount < 1) {
    imagecount = total;
  }
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagecount + ".jpg";
  **ChangeText(imagecount);**
}